# How do I display a certain post (ie. the fifth or sixth post only) in a loop completely different than the rest of the loop?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I want to display a twitter feed as one of the posts in a blog loop so I want to say something along the lines of: "If the fifth post then use this code (code pulling in twitter feed) instead of the 'content' code". How would I go about this?

```
<?php
        if ( have_posts() ) :
            // Start the Loop.
            while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

                get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );

            endwhile;
            // Previous/next post navigation.
            twentyfourteen_paging_nav();

        else :
            // If no content, include the "No posts found" template.
            get_template_part( 'content', 'none' );

        endif;
    ?>
```

Comment: Add a variable `$i = 0;` and then each loop increase it by 1. `$i++;` From there, `if($i == 5) { }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a variable counter, like this:

```
<?php
    if ( have_posts() ) :
        $i = 0;
        $featuredPostNumber = 5; //set this number to whatever you want to use as your featured number
        // Start the Loop.
        while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
            $i++;
            if($i==$featuredPostNumber){
                echo '<div class="featuredPost">';
                get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );
                echo '</div>';
            }else{
                get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );
            }
        endwhile;
        // Previous/next post navigation.
        twentyfourteen_paging_nav();

    else :
        // If no content, include the "No posts found" template.
        get_template_part( 'content', 'none' );

    endif;
?>
```

Your "featured post" would be wrapped in a div with the .featuredPost class, and can then be used to style differently.